ScFi - 3 guys attend a project sign-off that becomes increasingly tense
I've searched both IMDB and the web for the name of this movie but got no where.
I guess it was released within the past 5 years or so, and I saw it a couple of years ago.
It seems to be set in the USA/Canada and the spoken language is English.
Basic plot is that three software engineers attend a routine sign-off meeting for a project they were working on. Their work allows their clients to crack any computer security on the internet. However, things don't go as they expect and the atmosphere becomes very tense.
All the action takes place in the meeting room and there are probably only six characters involved. The three guys, a manager, project controller and some security officer. The project controller seems to work for the military-industrial complex.
All the characters are male but I can't recall any of them being so called big name stars although their acting and script was brilliant.

The movie is quite unusual in that everything takes place in one location  - the meeting room.
I think the two actors playing the 'project controller' and the more independent of the engineers were actors I had seen before so must be quite well known.
For some reason the movie feels like an Indie Australian or New Zealand movie - it reminds me of The Bank (2001) - although I still thinks its probably from USA/Canada.
To me, the production quality was excellent - cinematography, location, direction, acting and script. So guess it wasn't made on a shoe string and a lot of effort did go into into making it. Non of the actors were embarassed, self-conscious, clumsy or amateur - their characters seemed real.


Sounds like an interesting movie. Was it a "big" movie or more of an "independent" feel? Any idea how long it was - timewise?

It seemed an 'independent feel' and timewise it wasn't short, perhaps over 90 mins. It went quickly, even though it was quite technical with lots of talking. The writers must have had some technical knowledge as it  wasn't too far fetched, seemed very plausible but quite ominous.

So not really Science Fiction...more drama?

Yes, it was certainly drama, although the core idea was science fiction and how their software could change the world. Perhaps it might have come from a stage play.

...and the atmosphere becomes very tense. Do you remember anything specific? What exactly happens?

I don't want to give the plot away too much but you have three guys trying to get paid so they can leave the building but the 'firm' is playing hardball.  In the background is the firm's security guy who might be there to kill them.

Sounds a bit like Sneakers... but probably not.

Thanks for trying but no its not Sneakers.

I haven't seen the movie, but your description reminded me of "Primer", that could be it. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0390384/

Thanks for trying but no its not Primer - I actually watched Primer last week. I'm adding a few more thoughts to my question.

If there's a big twist you don't want to spoil for people you can describe it with >! at the start of the paragraph and it'll be hidden in a 'spoiler block' until someone clicks on it to show it. Just say as much as you can outside the spoiler block, e.g. "There's a twist, and the mood darkens and becomes intense about two thirds of the way through the movie when it becomes apparent that many at the company including some of the management didn't know that: >! the company was always planning to kill them when the project finished [or whatever the twist is]"

Thank you for your thoughts but I feel uncomfortable about putting the ending in even with the spoiler protection. Hopefully we'll know the title soon then can watch it. By the way, your example twist is great as I had no idea what was going to happen except an increasing sense of foreboding.

@Malkom_HAC - Making it harder by intentionally withholding information is just plain dumb.

Well I do really feel dumb now as can't even recall how it progressed after mid way. Anyhow, I'll try searching again with some new keywords - perhaps ChatGPT etc might find something.
